# работа с базой на клиенте

Tags: javascript, node.js

Пишу изоморфный модуль для работы с базой. Получается, что в месте самой выборки на клиенте должен передаваться запрос на сервер. Но это просто дыра в безопасности базы - кто угодно будет в состоянии работать с базой напрямую. Варианты шифрования и т.д. не спасут, т.к. можно взять код загружаемого js файла, прогнать через бъютифаер и получить функцию шифрования. Собственно вопрос - есть вариант безопасно построить взаимодействие клиента и сервера?

Comment: Смотря какая база. Но скорее всего, у вас в самый главный изъян в самом начале вопроса: "изоморфный модуль работы с базой". Клиент не должен сам работать с базой в принципе. Исключения бывают, но исчезающе редки.

Comment: Шлите запросы к базе не напрямую а через ваше node.js приложение. + согласен с @D-side, специфика очень сильно зависит от базы

Comment: Запрос понятное дело будет идти через через приложение. Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как  его валидировать. Любой код на клиенте можно взять и исполнить через консоль - и на сервере я не могу понять - выполнен этот код там где я задумывал или кто-то запустил его руками.

Comment: Если под запросом вы понимаете SQL код, тогда у вас действительно проблемы. Переходите на объектное представление запросов и у вас не будет проблем с валидацией.

Comment: Нет, вы не поняли. Для клиента **вообще не должно существовать базы данных как абстракции**, проксирование запросов приложением не решает проблемы. И протокол общения клиента с приложением не должен быть связан с базой данных вообще никак, база это внутренняя деталь приложения. Если хотите сделать что-то невозможным, сделайте это на уровне протокола, чтобы неразрешённые действия просто нельзя было по протоколу передать.